# Blender keeps showing me the same render even though i made changes to the 3d model

Tags: rendering

So I made my first 3d model and rendered it once. But when I added some things to the model and then rendered it, but it showed the previous render. I kept doing it but it never showed the changes that I made after the first render. I tried turning off the sequencer and compositioning like another forum said, but it still doesn't fix the problem
[image: This is the render]

[image: This is the current 3d model]

Comment: I forgot to say, the first image is the current render and the second is the 3d model i have currently made

Comment: maybe the camera is facing the other side

Comment: Suggestion Please. Put your first comment in the question itself.  Show more of the Blender UI in your image, perhaps the entire screen capture.  There are many ways to hide meshes. The UI may reveal any undesired settings.   Intentionally set or not.

Comment: @ShantanuAryan Thanks it works 